# Object: Deep omit

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a way to use `_.omit` on nested object properties?

I want this to happen:

```
schema = {
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  secret: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    private: true
  }
};

schema = _.nestedOmit(schema, 'private');

console.log(schema);
// Should Log
// {
//   firstName: {
//     type: String
//   },
//   secret: {
//     type: String,
//     optional: true
//   }
// }
```

`_.nestedOmit` obviously doesn't exist and just `_.omit` doesn't affect nested properties, but it should be clear what I'm looking for.

It also doesn't have to be underscore, but in my experience it often just makes things shorter and clearer.

Comment: Will the nesting be arbitrary or just one level?

Answer (score 8):

You could create a `nestedOmit` mixin that would traverse the object to remove the unwanted key. Something like

```
_.mixin({
    nestedOmit: function(obj, iteratee, context) {
        // basic _.omit on the current object
        var r = _.omit(obj, iteratee, context);

        //transform the children objects
        _.each(r, function(val, key) {
            if (typeof(val) === "object")
                r[key] = _.nestedOmit(val, iteratee, context);
        });

        return r;
    }
});
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/fez3eyw8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Detailed solution of this issue is posted in another thread. Please have a look at the below thread

**Link** - [Cleaning Unwanted Fields From GraphQL Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211778/cleaning-unwanted-fields-from-graphql-responses/51380645#51380645)