# Cleaning Unwanted Fields From GraphQL Responses

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql

I have an object that my GraphQL client requests.

It's a reasonably simple object:

```
type Element {
    content: [ElementContent]
    elementId: String
    name: String
    notes: String
    type: String
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String
  }
```

With the special type `ElementContent`, which is tiny and looks like this:

```
  type ElementContent {
    content: String
    locale: String
  }
```

Now, when I query this on the clientside, both the top level object and the lower level object has additional properties (which interfere with updating the object if I attempt to clone the body exactly-as-is);

Notably, GraphQL seems to supply a `__typename` property in the parent object, and in the child objects, they have typename and a `Symbol(id)` property as well.

[image]

I'd love to copy this object to state, update in state, then clone the state and ship it to my `update` mutation. However, I get roadblocked because of unknown properties that GraphQL itself supplies.

I've tried doing:

`delete element.__typename` to good effect, but then I also need to loop through the children (a dynamic array of objects), and likely have to remove those properties as well.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something during this equation, or I should just struggle through the code and loop + delete (I received errors attempting to do a forEach loop initially). Is there a better strategy for what I'm attempting to do? Or am I on the right path and just need some good loop code to clean unwanted properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187860/object-deep-omit

Answer (score 160, accepted):

There are three ways of doing this

**First way**

Update the client parameter like this it will omit the unwanted fields in graphql.

```js
apollo.create({
  link: http,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false
  })
});
```

**Second Way**

By using the [omit-deep](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/omit-deep) package and use it as a middleware

```
const cleanTypeName = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  if (operation.variables) {

    operation.variables = omitDeep(operation.variables,'__typename')
  }
  return forward(operation).map((data) => {
    return data;
  });
});
```

**Third Way**

Creating a custom middleware and inject in the apollo

```
const cleanTypeName = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  if (operation.variables) {
    const omitTypename = (key, value) => (key === '__typename' ? undefined : value);
    operation.variables = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(operation.variables), omitTypename);
  }
  return forward(operation).map((data) => {
    return data;
  });
});
```

and inject the middleware

```
const httpLinkWithErrorHandling = ApolloLink.from([
  cleanTypeName,
  retry,
  error,
  http,
]);
```

If you use fragments with the queries/mutations **Second Way** & **Third Way** is recommended.

Preferred method is **Third Way** Because it does not have any third pary dependency and no cache performance issues

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for me, the `__typename` is not within `operation.variables`.

Comment: Why do you use the incidence map `data => data`?

Comment: @qwerty that also works. I will update it accordingly

Comment: @qwerty. I reverified the function this works fine also can you please share the apollo config with me

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I was asking why do you use the `.map` that maps `data` to itself as in `.map((data) => { return data })`- I have seen it in almost every example, but I don't understand it. It does not manipulate anything in any way.

Comment: The first way worked for me w/ Angular8 client. Thanks!!

Comment: The second way shouldn't be used. `omit-deep` inserts an empty object to fields with `undefined` value which can break requests. Having a variable with `undefined` is useful when you take many values from a form with empty values and they are not required. See the [existing 2 years old PR](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/omit-deep/issues/8) and my [working example](https://repl.it/@Murillo2380/omit-deep-error)

Comment: First way fails for me. If you use fragment, you get an error, cause __typename is used to match node types for fragments... Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try second and third ways too.that resolves your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not applicable to many real-life cases.

First of all, the question was about GQL *responses*, and Option 2 and 3 only modify operation variables (which are sent to the server), not responses.

Only option 1 would cover both (probably), but then there's another problem: when schema is deeply nested and/or uses fragments, each option breaks cache, which relies on `__typename`.

Summing up, there is no good cover-all solution here. Some options may work for your case, but if you use fragments and/or cache, most surely you just need to live with `__typename`.

Comment: `Cannot delete property '__typename' of #<Object>`

Not working for me :(

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet you use

Comment: @piotr.d Have you tried something like this, where you keep the `__typename` field but just make it non-enumerable?: `const typeName = data.__typename; delete data.__typename; if (typeName) Object.defineProperty(data, "__typename", {value: typeName}); // defining it this way, makes the property non-enumerable`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to wipe up `__typename` from GraphQL response (from the root and its children), you can use [graphql-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-anywhere) package.

Something like:
`const wipedData = filter(inputFragment, rcvData);`

- `inputFragment` is a fragment defines the fields (You can see details [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/))
- `rcvData` is the received data from GraphQL query

By using the `filter` function, the `wipedData` includes only required fields you need to pass as mutation input.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did, to support file uploads as well. It's a merge of multiple suggestions I found on the Github thread here: [Feature idea: Automatically remove `__typename` from mutations](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2160)

```
import { parse, stringify } from 'flatted';

const cleanTypename = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const omitTypename = (key, value) => (key === '__typename' ? undefined : value);

    if ((operation.variables && !operation.getContext().hasUpload)) {
        operation.variables = parse(stringify(operation.variables), omitTypename);
    }

    return forward(operation);
});
```

Hooking up the rest of my `client.tsx` file, simplified:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
    return {
        headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${ token }` : '',
        },
    };
});



const httpLink = ApolloLink.from([
    cleanTypename,
    authLink.concat(upLoadLink),
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache,
});

export default client;
```

Now when I call mutations that are of type upload, I simply set the context `hasUpload` to true, as shown here:

```
UpdateStation({variables: { input: station }, context: {hasUpload: true }}).then()
```

Comment: This will not work if you upload a file with some variables with __typename in one request

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a TypeScript solution:

```
import cloneDeepWith from "lodash/cloneDeepWith";

export const omitTypenameDeep = (
  variables: Record<string, unknown>
): Record<string, unknown> =>
  cloneDeepWith(variables, (value) => {
    if (value && value.__typename) {
      const { __typename, ...valWithoutTypename } = value;
      return valWithoutTypename;
    }

    return undefined;
  });
```

```
const removeTypename = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const newOperation = operation;
  newOperation.variables = omitTypenameDeep(newOperation.variables);
  return forward(newOperation);
});

// ...

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([removeTypename, httpLink]),
});
```

Comment: Your function `omitTypenameDeep` is not correct because it won't do a deep clone (recursively).

Correction:

```ts

const omitTypenameDeep = (
  variables: Record<string, unknown>
): Record<string, unknown> =>
  cloneDeepWith(variables, (value) => {
    if (value?.__typename) {
      const { __typename, ...valWithoutTypename } = value
      return omitTypenameDeep(valWithoutTypename)
    }
    return undefined
  })

```

Answer (score 2):

Below approach worked for me so far in my use case.

```
const {
        loading,
        error,
        data,
      } = useQuery(gqlRead, {
        variables: { id },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        onCompleted: (data) => {
          const { someNestedData } = data;
          const filteredData = removeTypeNameFromGQLResult(someNestedData);
          //Do sth with filteredData
        },
      });
    
    //in helper
    export const removeTypeNameFromGQLResult = (result: Record<string, any>) => {
      return JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(result, (key, value) => {
          if (key === '__typename') return;
          return value;
        })
      );
    };
```

Comment: Using addTypename: false can cause perfomance and duplicate items in your cache so better leave it alone. Just get the data and normalize it i believe is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I've just published [graphql-filter-fragment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-filter-fragment) to help with this use case. I've [wrote in a bit more detail about the CRUD use case I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631523/remove-read-only-fields-before-mutation-in-graphql) that led me to this approach.

Example:

```
import {filterGraphQlFragment} from 'graphql-filter-fragment';
import {gql} from '@apollo/client/core';

const result = filterGraphQlFragment(
  gql`
    fragment museum on Museum {
      name
      address {
        city
      }
    }
  `,
  {
    __typename: 'Museum',
    name: 'Museum of Popular Culture',
    address: {
      __typename: 'MuseumAddress',
      street: '325 5th Ave N',
      city: 'Seattle'
    }
  }
);

expect(result).toEqual({
  name: 'Museum of Popular Culture',
  address: {
    city: 'Seattle'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Vanilla JS, recursive, and does not mutate the original object:

```
const removeAllTypenamesNoMutate = (item) => {
  if (!item) return;

  const recurse = (source, obj) => {
    if (!source) return;

    if (Array.isArray(source)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const item = source[i];
        if (item !== undefined && item !== null) {
          source[i] = recurse(item, item);
        }
      }
      return obj;
    } else if (typeof source === 'object') {
      for (const key in source) {
        if (key === '__typename') continue;
        const property = source[key];
        if (Array.isArray(property)) {
          obj[key] = recurse(property, property);
        } else if (!!property && typeof property === 'object') {
          const { __typename, ...rest } = property;
          obj[key] = recurse(rest, rest);
        } else {
          obj[key] = property;
        }
      }
      const { __typename, ...rest } = obj;

      return rest;
    } else {
      return obj;
    }
  };

   return recurse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)), {});
};
```